# Windows 10 using Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

Have a spread sheet of data (names, addresses, and volunteer status (yes/no). I call this sheet "rawdata". I want to create another sheet("volunteer") based on the contents of volunteer status (if yes, fill cells with names, addresses, etc, If no, move to the next person. Ive tried vlookup but wind up with cells that meet the criteria (name, addresses, etc) and #N/A for those that dont. Tried using an If, but again same results. Any advice?

Comment: Yes and it doesnt give me what I need

Answer (score 1):

Say the raw data is like:

[image]

In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(C2="yes",1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Each "yes" row is marked.  In the other worksheet, cell **A1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(rawdata!A$1:A$23,MATCH(ROW(),rawdata!$D$1:$D$23,0)),"")
```

copy this both across and downward:

[image]

Comment: That works the first time, but if i go into rawdata sheet and update "no" to "yes", the second sheet doesnt  updat with the new person.

Comment: @MichaelBuro  Make sure calculation is set to automatic

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the Sort & Filter options in Excel.

Just copy the sheet with raw data, select all data, click on Sort & Filter, pick the column where you've put whether or not they volunteer. Select Yes (or whatever value means they do) and only the volunteers will show up.

Comment: I know I can do that, but I have multiple columns indicating various volunteer positions. The would mean copying the same data over and over again to get separate lists to share. I just want to be able to replicate the values I need across multiple worksheets by only updating the main page.